# Javascript doesn't work in normal mode

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here is my button:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-ok btn-edit-piattaforma" onclick="salvaClick();" data-loading-text="<i class='fa fa-spinner fa-spin'></i>Salva">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></i>Salva
        </button>
```

[image]

Here is my javascript:

```
var salvaClick = function () {
    try {
        buttonSalva.load();//seems not work if in normal mode; if I set breakpoint at this line, it works.
        buttonStatus.disable();//works
        if (!valid()) {
            console.log("valid failure!");
        }
        else {
            Save(); //this is my business logic function
        }
        buttonSalva.reset();
        buttonStatus.enable();
    } catch (e) {
        //console.log(e.message);
        buttonSalva.reset();
        buttonStatus.enable();
    }
}

var buttonStatus = {
    disable: function () {
        $('.btn-edit-piattaforma').attr("disabled", true);
    },
    enable: function () {
        $('.btn-edit-piattaforma').attr("disabled", false);
    }
}

var buttonSalva = {
    load: function () {
        $('.btn-edit-piattaforma.btn-ok').button('loading');
    },
    reset: function () {
        $('.btn-edit-piattaforma.btn-ok').button('reset');
    }
}
```

The scenario: I want to display the icon showing that it's loading when users click button "Salva". When I run in normal mode, it doesn't display. But when I set breakpoint and run in debug mode (F12), it displays the icon after I click button. I don't understand why. Anyone here can explain? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your markup looks malformed. Is it actually like that?

Comment: I copy from Visual Studio

Comment: Then it is invalid

Comment: check yo html. it's invalid

Comment: Please take a look at the image attached

Answer (score 0):

Normal HTML doesn't support two-way data binding. The changes in the script file will not reflect as such in your view in normal mode. When you set a debugger, it runs because it gets time for the DOM updation. Better you set a timeout and show the spinner first and only after a delay, load your script functionality.

Comment: In document ready function, I show the button. So if the button is available for user to click, the page is fully loaded.